# @ Reference Control in .aspx, but class not found in respective aspx.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hopefully the title made at least some sense.

I've been fiddling with ASP.NET and C# for the first time today - following a tutorial.  I have comfortably got as far as [this](http://asp.net-tutorials.com/user-controls/using/); however, when I try to implement:

```
<%@ Reference Control="~/UserInfoBoxControl.ascx" %>
```

and

```
UserInfoBoxControl userInfoBoxControl = (UserInfoBoxControl)LoadControl("~/UserInfoBoxControl.ascx");
userInfoBoxControl.UserName = "John Doe";
userInfoBoxControl.UserAge = 78;
userInfoBoxControl.UserCountry = "Spain";
UserInfoBoxPH.Controls.Add(userInfoBoxControl);
```

I get

```
The type or namespace name 'UserInfoBoxControl' could not be found...
```

My Java background makes me now want to 'import' this control class with `using`, although I understand the `@ Reference` does this job.  I've attempted some rudimentary troubleshooting by eliminating code from earlier in the tutorial, but with no luck.  From what I've read elsewhere, the code looks all okay, so I'm a bit confused and keen to move on in my tutorial :)

Thanks!

**Edit:**

I'm still at this hurdle, so I thought it would ultimately be easiest to just dump all my code:

[Default.aspx](http://pastebin.com/embed_iframe.php?i=CDsga2Rg)

[Default.aspx.cs](http://pastebin.com/embed_iframe.php?i=D1YqTPwK) (the error occurs when declaring `userInfoBoxControl`)

[UserInfoBoxControl.ascx](http://pastebin.com/embed_iframe.php?i=RKnHsuGa)

[UserInfoBoxControl.ascx.cs](http://pastebin.com/embed_iframe.php?i=GFndPyJ1)

Comment: best solution for references and usings is resharper: http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/ :)

Comment: @sasjaq: as much as I love Resharper, this has nothing to do with it. Moreover, it has lots of cool features, but all it does with usings and references is tidying them up. Is it worth installing a commercial product just for that?

Comment: is there a reason why you want to dynamically load the .ascx user control?

Comment: @prashantht: I think he's trying to follow the example in the tutorial (see link in the question)

Comment: @prashantht quite right Paolo, I'm just doing it as an exercise

Comment: @PaoloTedesco: I checked it; latter part contains the dynamic part

Comment: @PaoloTedesco from context I don't know, if he will better solution for creating dynamic controls or just get the right reference... for the second point, resharper makes it for us :) I think, for somebody starting with c# is resharper a must :) to the comercionality, resharper is for 30 days free...

Comment: @c24w: could you please post your control's code (at least the directives in the ascx file)? I suspect that you forgot some attribute in the declarations...

Comment: @sasjaq In the context of the question a third party tool is irrelevant. resharper is ofcourse helpful; but not going to help much with learning (to understand how things work); It is there to organize and speedup development (again not a freeware to play with after the 30 day trial)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you declared everything correctly, then your code should work.

The [Register directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c76dd5k1%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is needed to reference the control in pages, user controls etc.

The [Reference directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w70c655a%28v=vs.100%29), instead, *"Indicates that another user control, page source file, or arbitrary file located at some virtual path should be dynamically compiled and linked against the current ASP.NET file (Web page, user control, or master page) in which this directive is declared."*

It's just a guess, but is it possible that you declared your cotrol in a single file (i.e. the C# code is not in a separate file) and you forgot the "className" attribute in the `@ Control` directive?

**EDIT**: I have seen your code, the problem is that *the files* are named "UserInfoBoxControl", but the name of the class is `WebUserControl`:

```
public partial class WebUserControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl {
```

Your `@Reference` directive is importing *the file* "~/UserInfoBoxControl.ascx", but the type name is WebUserControl.
Try this, it should compile:

```
WebUserControl userInfoBoxControl = (WebUserControl)LoadControl("~/UserInfoBoxControl.ascx");
```

Comment: I have declared them separately, i.e. `UserInfoBoxControl.ascx` & `UserInfoBoxControl.ascx.cs`.  There was no mention of `className` in the tutorial, but I put it in as `ClassName="UserInfoBoxControl"` in `UserInfoBoxControl.ascx` anyway, although nothing changed :( (I've posted links to my code in  my original post). Thanks!

Comment: Thank you!!! Such a trivial oversight by me - I'm used to Netbeans refactoring and enforcing that class names match the file they are in (in Java).  I can continue with my tutorial :D

Comment: @c24w: You're welcome :) Visual Studio will ask you, without enforcing it, if you want to rename the corresponding class when you rename a file, but only with "regular" classes, and not with web pages or controls.

Answer (score 1):

You would import a namespace in the page directive. You register user controls:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="UserInfoBox" Src="UserInfoBoxControl.ascx" %>
```

EDIT: (from my comment) reference the namespace ASP:

```
using ASP;
```

Comment: You might also need to reference ASP in the code behind at the top: using ASP;

Comment: +1: The answer is right, but what's the deal with the `using ASP;` comment? Pretty sure that namespace doesn't exist.

Comment: Isn't the `Register` directive just to use the control in the aspx file? What he's trying to do here is to reference the type in the .cs file, and for that the `Reference` directive should be enough...

Comment: @PaoloTedesco - I think you're right. I was just trying to clear up the "Import" question.